# SharePoint 2019 User Profile Service Application could not be provisioned

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

When creating User Profile Service Application,gives invalid column name 'RecordId' error.

[image: Error]
I tried following action,

- create user profile service with powershell but **same result**
- create user profile service Configuration Wizards but **same result**
- Manage Service Application add new service on Central Admin but **same result**
- added February 2019 CU(KB4462171-KB4462170) and again create service but **same result**

I checked ULS Viewer with Correlation ID;

High Error; [image: High Error]

Exception; [image: Exception Error]

Unexpected;[image: Unexpected Error]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is big I and small i(Maybe due to language mismatch between farm and db). There is syntax eror on sql query file.

For Solution,

- Open Query File (profilesrp.sql)(C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\SQL\SPS )
- take backup this file.
  [image]
- Edit this file on line 16583 and 16635

[image]

[image]

4)Start Configuration Wizard on Central Admin and create UserProfile Service.
Best regard.